# compare time-dependent proportions to baseline

Tags: time-series, proportion, independence

I measured changes in the appearance of chronic wounds. There are four levels of this variable that can be ordered from the worst to best as necrotic < sloughy < granulating < epithelialising. There are proportions of the set of patients with corresponding levels such as:
[image]

The wounds were measured at the baseline on whole set of patients (n = 57), after 2 weeks (n = 56), 4 wks (n = 54), 6 wks (n = 45), ...12 wks (n = 18). The patients healed throughout the study, and therefore n decreases in time. How to test, if the variable at the particular time improved relatively to the baseline?